# Custom action, remove extra fields from details

Tags: lightning-experience, quickaction, detail

I have created an action for activity based on task. I have removed a few fields from the form, so the fields in the image (activity type, comments) are created by me and those are the only ones show on the activity tab for this action.

I want to remove the type field, cause that is confusing to show in the details. How can I remove it from the details?

Here is the layout I have: 
[image]

clicking here to go to details:
[image]

Here is the action under account: 
[image]

How can I remove the type field only for this action? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Based on the comments - you seem to be asking to modify the Compact Layout. If that's the scenario, then refer to steps below:

- Object Manager --> Task
- Go to the Compact Layouts
- Remove the *Type* field from the Selected Fields list
  [image]

For details, refer to the [Compact Layouts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=compact_layout_overview.htm&type=5) docs.

Comment: It's not there in the layout. I removed it. It shows up in the detail though.

Comment: Is this a regular details page or on a quick action layout?

Comment: this is by clicking on the next steps task.

Comment: I have updated my answer, it seems you are viewing a record's details page and that you will need to edit the respective page layout for that purpose.

Comment: Added an image how I am getting to details. Trying your solution.

Comment: That's the details page, so the steps I have provided to edit the details page should work.

Comment: The quick action I created is for account. I can't see it in the Task.

Comment: You have to edit the Task details layout, because you are viewing a Task based on your screenshot. You won't get the quick action created on Account on a Task.

Comment: Does this affect all the tasks? I just want to remove it for this action, not all the tasks. I am posting an image for my action which is under account, based on target object Task.

Comment: image posted in the question.

Comment: It will affect all tasks if you have a same detail page layout. Please note that the action layout and details layout are related to two different objects here. I will recommend you go through [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_customization/lex_customization_page_layouts) and [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_customization/lex_customization_actions) trailhead modules to get more information on the topic.

Comment: exactly. my question is how to customize the details layout for an action.

Comment: There's no details layout for an action, the layout that you see is used only for create/update actions. You may be referring to compact layout, if that's what you need to modify, I have updated the answer.

Comment: I don't want to remove type for all the tasks. Just for this action.

Comment: You cannot do it that way. Your action is for Account, the layout is for Task. If you have specific needs, you will need to create a custom compact layout. Refer to the help docs I linked in the answer.